# Java calendar library with support for recurring events / exceptions, etc

Tags: library, java, calendar, simulation

I am looking for a calendar module/library that I could use in my simulation. My idea is to fill such calendar with events, single shot and recurring. This calendar should be able to give me next upcoming event or list events occurring during given day (date). I will also need to be able to reschedule single occurrences of recurring events (e.g., reschedule occurrence of recurring event that would fall onto Saturday to Monday) or delete occurrences of recurring events.

So far I have only found [ical4j](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page). But I do not specifically need iCalendar support so I am looking for alternatives.

While at this point my implementation language is Java, I would be willing to switch to Python or Perl or C++ if there is some kind of awesome library that would totally rock in one of the tree languages. :)

Comment: As far as I understand you need the time management library, no GUI components needed?

Comment: @Fractaliste: Yes, I need something that will compute the event occurrences correctly. I do not need a GUI of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this library. It has a date calculator:
[https://github.com/Appendium/objectlabkit/](https://github.com/Appendium/objectlabkit)